# Extracting information from web-pages using NER

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

My task is to extract information from a various web-pages of a particular site. Now, the information to be extracted can be of the form as product name, product id, price, etc. The information is given in text using natural language. Also, I have been asked to extract that information using some Machine Learning algorithm. I thought of using NER (Named Entity Recognition) and training it on custom training data (which I can prepare using the scraped data and manually labeling the integers/data as required). I wanted to know if the model can even work this way?

Also, let me know if I can improve this question further.

Answer (score 0):

You say a **particular site**. I am assuming that it means you have some fair idea of what the structures of webpages are, if the data is in table form or a free text form, how the website generally looks. In this case, a simple regex (prices, ids etc) supported by some POS tagger to extract product names and all is enough for you. A supervised approach is definitely an overkill and might underperform than the simpler regex.

Comment: As I mentioned, the information in the text or website as you say is given in natural language. Hence, there is no particular format in the information given.

Comment: The data is not in a table or any structured format. Also, I have been particularly told to do this using machine learning.

Comment: I will still maintain, supervised approach to price extraction is surely an overkill. You should ask those people what is the reason behind them asking you to use machine learning and then update the question.

Comment: Okay, sure. But for now, if I trained the model on the training data using manual labeling (if I considered about 300-400 such product pages) and ran it on the test data, will I be able to get any good results?

Comment: @Abhinav No. Especially for prices and product names, it will be a bad idea.